# Travis CI R package oldrel error: no output received in the last 10 minutes

Tags: r, travis-ci, r-package

I recently hooked up a github repo containing an R package to Travis CI. The package is building fine with current release (`release`) and development release (`devel`) of R, but gives an error with the old release (`oldrel`, i.e., R version 3.2.5).

The build does not throw an error but terminate with the following message:

```
No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates
a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

The build has been terminated
```

The latest builds can be found there: https://travis-ci.org/lnalborczyk/ESTER

And my `.travis.yml` file is:

```
language: R
sudo: false
cache: packages
r:
- oldrel
- release
- devel
```

Does someone know what might be the origin of this problem and whether this behaviour would be problematic in the perspective of a submission to the CRAN ?

### EDIT

I know that `travis_wait` would allow to extend the length of the building time but it does not explain why the package is actually building fine (in ~5mn) on current and development releases while not building on the old release of R (cf. my comment below).

Comment: Have you parallelism in your package? I had a similar issue (but it is weird that this appear only for the oldrel).

Comment: Hey, good to know that parallelism might be a problem, but no parallelism in my package...

Comment: The difference between [oldrel log](https://travis-ci.org/lnalborczyk/ESTER/jobs/287116635) and [release log](https://travis-ci.org/lnalborczyk/ESTER/jobs/287116636) is in line 839: "could not download cache" (section "Setting up build cache"). So for oldrel travis attempts to install all package dependencies, and this may take quite a lot of time.

Comment: I think this is rather a problem of travis builder for oldrel, not yours.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`travis_wait`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received)

You can make travis wait on no-output builds for up to the max runtime (50 minutes)

Comment: Hey, `travis_wait` would indeed allow to extend the build, but it does not explain why the package is actually building fine in ~5mn on current and devel releases, but is not building (in more than 20mn) on the old release, right ? Anyway, I will try `travis_wait`and see whether it brings some insights...